# Compiling Unix tools for android

Tags: android, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I want to use some unix tools on my rooted android arm6 based phone. I will be using cross compiler tools [provided here](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm). If I want to compile `gnu netcat`, how can I set the cross compiler prefix to `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` and how to enable static linking (no shared library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you particularly need to build against a more standard libc than bionic, you can just use the ndk's toolchain, either by copying the hello-jni example and changing BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY to BUILD_EXECUTABLE in the jni/Android.mk or using the script to generate a stand alone toolchain.  You may want to use the V=1 option to the ndk-build script to see the commands it's issuing to its gcc.

Otherwise you may need to pass the prefix to the configure script or manually edit it into the Makefile for the project.  This often has not gone well as many projects have make systems not really set up for cross compiling, I've had to resort to editing the configure script to set prefixes and skip tests where it tries to execute a test program.

An option that sometimes works when the build system is more complicated than the project requires is to do a configure for your host (let's hope that's linux).  Then manually edit the generated Makefile to change anything needed to build for android instead.  Might not be a bad idea to do a clean just in case (especially if you did a test host build).  And then do the build which will pick up the arm compiler from your Makefile modifications.

Lastly, if you can be content with the original netcat by Hobbit rather than the gnu version, you hardly need to port it to android yourself as that's already been done.  There's already an android version in the google tree at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/netcat
 which may be on your device already (as 'nc'), and is definitely included in alternate ROMs such as Cyanogenmod.

Comment: I use an unofficial cyanogenmod. And it doesn't have nc. When I do `which nc`, nothing gets returned. Even rsync wasn't there, but I couls get rsync binary from google code pages. 'nc' is not avaiable anyewhere in binary form.

Comment: nc is most definitely in cyanogenmod, and has been for over a year.  Try /system/xbin/nc  rsync is there too.

Comment: I searched in `/system/xbin` too. It isn't there. Here is the `ls -l` of `/system/xbin`. http://pastebin.com/hJ8NWmZ5 The rsync found there was later added by me, time stamp of the rsync binary makes it clear.

Comment: Which version of cyanogenmod is this?  It's there in the version I downloaded a year ago, and there in CM 7.02 I grabbed this week.  You can probably get it out of cm or the official vendor image for your phone and adb push it on, android binaries tend to be portable unless they do unusual things.

Comment: @vadim - it's probably not worth fixing these links, as most of them simply aren't relevant any more, and every one you edit *needlessly* goes to the top of the page of questions as a result of being edited.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you please point me to the page you are talking about?

Comment: Everytime you edit a question, it needlessly goes to the top of every page on which it appears - main SO page, main Android tag page, etc.  These questions mostly reference *ancient* Android versions so really aren't of interest to many people anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to cross-compile rsync for Android using Ubuntu's arm-linux-gnueabi toolchain. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130889/build-rsync-for-android/18032833).