# Build Rsync for Android

Tags: android, build, rsync

I have downloaded rsync from http://rsync.samba.org/
anyone knows how to compile the source code to be deployed in an Android Device?

Answer (score 13):

You can compile without the NDK assuming you statically link. This works for me on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail.

Install the cross compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Download rsync:

```
wget http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz
tar -zxv -f rsync-3.0.9.tar.gz
cd rsync-3.0.9
```

Compile with the cross compiler, using static linking:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS="-static"
make
```

You'll get some warnings along the lines of `Using X in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`. But so far, rsync has worked for me.

And finally, install to your phone (assumes you are using SSHDroid):

```
scp -P 2222 rsync root@$PHONE_IP:/data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/dropbear
```

Comment: Note that you have to move the binary to /data (e.g., /data/local/tmp) and make it executable (chmod 0777 rsync) before it will run.

Comment: what is the  binary .can you help me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529567/compile-the-rsync-source-code-and-deploy-it-to-android-device

Comment: I am curious if you got rsync to work on Android? Does it still work? Can you sync your photos/ videos easily to a server this way?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the Android NDK found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)
There are examples included on the web page and download of how to compile C code for Android.

From the [NDK Website:](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

> The NDK provides:
>
> A set of tools and build files used to generate native code libraries
>   from C and C++ sources 
>   A way to embed the corresponding native
>   libraries into an application package file (.apk) that can be deployed
>   on Android devices A set of native system headers and libraries that
>   will be supported in all future versions of the Android platform,
>   starting from Android 1.5. Applications that use native activities
>   must be run on Android 2.3 or later. Documentation, samples, and
>   tutorials

I did also find [this](http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App) if it's close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I already downloaded NDK.  What I am trying to do is to compile rsync source codes into an executable binary so that i could invoke this binary inside java codes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you don't want to compile a library but make an executable file. I think this is quite difficult to achieve and personally I would see if I could make the code into a library and use it that way. I'm included some links and info in my answer above.

Comment: hi kerubu, sorry i didnt notice the second link of your answer.  I also stumbled upon on that site. but I end up compiling  the codes using the NDK provided cross-compilers. Thanks.