# compile the rsync source code and deploy it to Android Device

Tags: android, build, rsync

i have  read  [Build Rsync for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130889/build-rsync-for-android/18032833)  ,and to do as @Ben Challenor methods.  i do it :

Compile with the cross compiler, using static linking:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS="-static"
make
```

but i donot know which code i need to put it to the android.the lib folder of the rsync_3.1.0

or the .so file of  the lib rsync_3.1.0 ,or the all files of the rsync_3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

only put the rsync  file to the system/xbin all is ok