# How does an Android app install a required unix program such as rsync?

Tags: java, android, shell, exec, rsync

I'm working on an app that wraps a unix utility, rsync. I understand how to make shell command calls in java by using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) but rsync is not installed by default on android. How can I install rsync so I can test my App, and furthermore how can my App install it alongside itself when it is downloaded to a new device?

I've tried looking up how to install rsync but since it comes pre-installed on almost every unix flavor all instructions are out of date. I've tried some combinations of basic install commands but android doesn't even recognize 'apt'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a dupe. That doesn't tell me how to install rsync. Only how to run it. And it's not about running it from an app. It is about running it manually. It requires installing some other app and editing a config file which definitely should not be necessary for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18032833/2970947) **is** what you want.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. I'm gonna try compiling rsync with the NDK. Thanks